# amdgpu: module ABI major version (23) doesn't match the server's version (24)

Tags: upgrade, login, xorg, amdgpu

After upgrading to 19.10, I can't log in. I'm stuck in a login loop. I searched around and found some suggestions to change permissions on the .Xauthority file, but I don't have a .Xauthority file in my home directory.

I then tried running `startx` from the terminal and got:

```
amdgpu: module ABI major version (23) doesn't match the server's version (24)
```

I tried upgrading amdgpu, but it seems to be up to date. Any ideas?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I suspect the local repository for amdgpu graphics driver was not updated, but I have currently  no idea how to update it manually. Hope there is something on AMD's web pages. Alternatively I'll try to switch back to the Ubuntu native driver.

Comment: Interesting. I went over to the AMD pages and didn't find any references to this. By switching back to the Ubuntu native driver, do you mean uninstalling amdgpu-pro? https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing the uninstalling the open source amdgpu drivers. If this issue is happening to you, take a look at the following thread for context.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2441792